# Calculating weekly wages

Tags: java

This is the code:

```
    double calculateWeeklyPay(double hoursWorked)
{
    double pay;
    if(hoursWorked > 40)
    {
        double overtime = hoursWorked - 40;
        pay = (40 * hourlyPayRate) + (overtime * hourlyPayRate);
        return pay;
    }else pay = hoursWorked * hourlyPayRate;
    return pay;
}
```

and I'm trying to use this:

```
        System.out.println("Weekly pay: $" + aaron.calculateWeeklyPay(46));
```

but it's only returning 0 dollars and I'm not sure why? Thank you for any help.

Comment: We need to know the value of hourlyPayRate

Comment: What is `hourlyPayRate` ? If it is 0, then the function returns 0 as well

Comment: We know hoursWorked; it's 46.  But if hourlyPayRate is 0, then zero is the correct answer.

Comment: Where is hourlyPayRate declared and initialized?

Comment: put System.out.println(hourlyPayRate); right before the if to see what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `hourlyPayRate` is 0. You are multiplying by `hourlyPayRate` twice and adding them therefore if the variable is 0 the result will always be 0 (anything times 0 = 0).

I can only guess without reading more of your code but I assume in your constructor you are setting this value to 0 so you might want to add another argument into your constructor.

Example:

What I believe you have:

```
public Employee() 
{
    this.hourlyPayRate = 0;
}
```

What you should have:

```
public Employee(double hourlyPayRate) //Also any arguments you already had.
{
    //Your current code
    this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why you get "0" back. Maybe your hourlyPayRate is zero? Is it a global var?

This Code works fine:

```
class workPay {
double calculateWeeklyPay(double hoursWorked, double hourlyPayRate)
{
    double pay;
    if(hoursWorked > 40) 
    {
        double overtime = hoursWorked - 40;
        pay = (40 * hourlyPayRate) + (overtime * hourlyPayRate);
        return pay;
    } else pay = hoursWorked * hourlyPayRate;
    return pay;
}   

public void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(calculateWeeklyPay(46, 80));
    }
}
```